# MySQL LEFT JOIN with SUM is slow

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, sum, left-join

I need ideas to optimize this query:

```
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY U.Id
```

Some information about the tables:

1. `users` table: 10,000+ records
2. `payments` table: 2,000,000+ records, indexed on `UserId` column

The query takes up to 2 minutes. By investigating the query, I found out that the `SUM` function is the reason why the query is slow. Tried executing the query without the `SUM` takes less than 2 seconds.

Is there any room to improve this query? Thanks

**EDIT 1**

This is what I got when using the `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref             rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      U       ALL                                                         8304    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      P       ref     UserId          UserId  5           Database.U.Id   361     ""
```

The index `payments.UserId` is being used in the query. Any thoughts on this?

**EDIT 2**
Table Information:

```
users   "CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `StatusId` int(11) default NULL,
  `Name` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `TimeZone` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `StatusId` (`StatusId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_User_Status` FOREIGN KEY (`StatusId`) REFERENCES `userStatus` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"

payments    "CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `UserId` int(11) default NULL,  
  `Description` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `Debit` decimal(11,2) default NULL,
  `Credit` decimal(11,2) default NULL,
  `Date` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Payment_User` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
```

Comment: hi kael, do you index on this columns? `payments.UserId` and `users.Id`

Comment: Hi John, yes they are both indexed. `users.Id` is the primary key, i think it is already a unique index.

Comment: how about on `payments.UserId`?

Comment: Run `explain` and you might see why there's such a `cost`

Comment: @KaeL it's easy, just write `explain` before your query ([*read more*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)...)

Comment: Thanks alfasin and Adrian, I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178441/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-sum-in-mysql), I can't speed up the `SUM` function. The main issue here is that I'm selecting a huge number of records.

I thought of redesigning the `users` table, adding a new column like `TotalPayment` which will hold the total `credit` minus `debit` amount from the `payments` table. I know it disobeys the database normalization rules, but I guess this redesign is for saving performance.

Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Comment: I've encountered issues like this, when the character sets/collations of the fields I was joining where different. If one was `latin`, and the other was `utf8`, a sub-second query would take 5+ *minutes* to run.  You might also experience this if one field in `INT`, and the other is `INT UNSIGNED`. To identify these types of issue, can you include the output of  `SHOW CREATE TABLE users; SHOW CREATE TABLE payments;`?

Comment: Thanks Ross, added the table code in my question, sorry for the late response.

Comment: Kael, you're performance problem lies elsewhere (like in your `my.cnf` file). I created a `users` and `payments` table, loaded them with 20,000 and 2,000,000 records, and ran your query in 16.1 seconds (averaged over 5 runs). After I added my indexes, and added the `FORCE INDEX` options, the query run in 0.9 seconds (on average)

Comment: Wow that's great, I'll check your answer. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_status ON users (StatusId, Id);
CREATE INDEX ix_userid ON payments (UserId, Credit, Debit);
```

And add `FORCE INDEX` options:

```
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY
        U.Id;
```

Your query will almost certainly perform better.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I'll try this one.

Comment: Sorry Ross, created the indexes and adjusted the query using `FORCE INDEX`, execution time is still over 2 minutes. Thanks for the idea though +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Kael, here's the script I ran, and the output from it, to show the indexes and query I provided in my first answer reduced the query time from about 14.3 seconds to just 0.75 seconds:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payments;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userStatus;

CREATE TABLE userStatus (
    Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY  (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE users (
    Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    StatusId int(11) default NULL,
    Name varchar(60) default NULL,
    TimeZone varchar(100) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (Id),
    KEY StatusId (StatusId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_User_Status FOREIGN KEY (StatusId) REFERENCES userStatus (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE payments (
    Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    UserId int(11) default NULL,  
    Description varchar(200) default NULL,
    Debit decimal(11,2) default NULL,
    Credit decimal(11,2) default NULL,
    Date datetime default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (Id),
    KEY UserId (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_User FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES users (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ids;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM; -- must be MyISAM
INSERT INTO ids SET id = NULL; # inserts a 1
UPDATE ids SET id=0;
ALTER TABLE ids AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #      1      1
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #      2      2
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #      4      4
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #      8      8
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #     10     16
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #     20     32
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #     40     64
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #     80    128
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #    100    256
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #    200    512
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #    400  1,024
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #    800  2,048
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #   1000  4,096
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #   2000  8,192
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids; #   4000 16,384

INSERT INTO 
userStatus
(id)
SELECT
id
FROM
ids
WHERE
id > 0
ORDER BY
id
LIMIT 2;

INSERT INTO 
users
(Id, StatusId)
SELECT
id,
IF(RAND() < .9, 1, 2) -- 90% of users are 'Active'
FROM
ids
WHERE
id > 0 AND
id <= 20000
ORDER BY
id;

INSERT INTO
payments
(Id, UserId, Debit, Credit, `Date`)
SELECT
NULL,
i1.id,
ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 2),
ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 2),
NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 86400 * 1000) SECOND
FROM
ids i1,
ids i2 
WHERE
i1.id > 0 AND
i1.id <= 20000 AND
i2.id < 100
ORDER BY
RAND();

EXPLAIN
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY U.Id;

SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY U.Id;

SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY U.Id;

SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY U.Id;

CREATE INDEX ix_status ON users (StatusId, Id);
CREATE INDEX ix_userid ON payments (UserId, Credit, Debit);

EXPLAIN
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY
        U.Id;

SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY
        U.Id;

SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY
        U.Id;

SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 /* Active Users Only */
    GROUP BY
        U.Id;
```

and here's the output:

```
[ross@titanv ~]$ mysql -vvv < ex.sql temp
--------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payments
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

--------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

--------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userStatus
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

--------------
CREATE TABLE userStatus (
        Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        PRIMARY KEY  (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

--------------
CREATE TABLE users (
        Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        StatusId int(11) default NULL,
        Name varchar(60) default NULL,
        TimeZone varchar(100) default NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (Id),
        KEY StatusId (StatusId),
        CONSTRAINT FK_User_Status FOREIGN KEY (StatusId) REFERENCES userStatus (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

--------------
CREATE TABLE payments (
        Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        UserId int(11) default NULL,  
        Description varchar(200) default NULL,
        Debit decimal(11,2) default NULL,
        Credit decimal(11,2) default NULL,
        Date datetime default NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (Id),
        KEY UserId (UserId),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_User FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES users (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

--------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ids
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

--------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (
        id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SET id = NULL
--------------

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

--------------
UPDATE ids SET id=0
--------------

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

--------------
ALTER TABLE ids AUTO_INCREMENT=1
--------------

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 16 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 16  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 32 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 32  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 64 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 64  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 128 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 128  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 256 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 256  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 512 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 512  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 1024 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1024  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 2048 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2048  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 4096 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4096  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 8192 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 8192  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO ids SELECT NULL FROM ids
--------------

Query OK, 16384 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 16384  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO 
userStatus
(id)
SELECT
id
FROM
ids
WHERE
id > 0
ORDER BY
id
LIMIT 2
--------------

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO 
users
(Id, StatusId)
SELECT
id,
IF(RAND() < .9, 1, 2) 
FROM
ids
WHERE
id > 0 AND
id <= 20000
ORDER BY
id
--------------

Query OK, 20000 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 20000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
INSERT INTO
payments
(Id, UserId, Debit, Credit, `Date`)
SELECT
NULL,
i1.id,
ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 2),
ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 2),
NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 86400 * 1000) SECOND
FROM
ids i1,
ids i2 
WHERE
i1.id > 0 AND
i1.id <= 20000 AND
i2.id < 100
ORDER BY
RAND()
--------------

Query OK, 2000000 rows affected (21.52 sec)
Records: 2000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
EXPLAIN
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY U.Id
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref       | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | U     | ref  | StatusId      | StatusId | 5       | const     | 10274 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | ref  | UserId        | UserId   | 5       | temp.U.Id |     1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

--------------
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY U.Id
--------------

+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
| Id    | Name | CreditAmount | DebitAmount |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
|     1 | NULL |     47824.73 |    49580.71 |
|     2 | NULL |     46426.02 |    52019.69 |
...
| 19999 | NULL |     50041.10 |    47696.88 |
| 20000 | NULL |     51923.69 |    50349.38 |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
18057 rows in set (14.60 sec)

--------------
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY U.Id
--------------

+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
| Id    | Name | CreditAmount | DebitAmount |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
|     1 | NULL |     47824.73 |    49580.71 |
|     2 | NULL |     46426.02 |    52019.69 |
...
| 19999 | NULL |     50041.10 |    47696.88 |
| 20000 | NULL |     51923.69 |    50349.38 |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
18057 rows in set (14.10 sec)

--------------
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN payments P ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY U.Id
--------------

+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
| Id    | Name | CreditAmount | DebitAmount |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
|     1 | NULL |     47824.73 |    49580.71 |
|     2 | NULL |     46426.02 |    52019.69 |
...
| 19999 | NULL |     50041.10 |    47696.88 |
| 20000 | NULL |     51923.69 |    50349.38 |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
18057 rows in set (14.17 sec)

--------------
CREATE INDEX ix_status ON users (StatusId, Id)
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
CREATE INDEX ix_userid ON payments (UserId, Credit, Debit)
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.09 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
EXPLAIN
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY
        U.Id
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref       | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | U     | ref  | ix_status     | ix_status | 5       | const     | 10274 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | ref  | ix_userid     | ix_userid | 5       | temp.U.Id | 10002 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

--------------
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY
        U.Id
--------------

+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
| Id    | Name | CreditAmount | DebitAmount |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
|     1 | NULL |     47824.73 |    49580.71 |
|     2 | NULL |     46426.02 |    52019.69 |
...
| 19999 | NULL |     50041.10 |    47696.88 |
| 20000 | NULL |     51923.69 |    50349.38 |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
18057 rows in set (0.75 sec)

--------------
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY
        U.Id
--------------

+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
| Id    | Name | CreditAmount | DebitAmount |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
|     1 | NULL |     47824.73 |    49580.71 |
|     2 | NULL |     46426.02 |    52019.69 |
...
| 19999 | NULL |     50041.10 |    47696.88 |
| 20000 | NULL |     51923.69 |    50349.38 |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
18057 rows in set (0.75 sec)

--------------
SELECT U.Id
    , U.Name
    , SUM(P.Credit) AS CreditAmount
    , SUM(P.Debit) AS DebitAmount
    FROM 
        users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status)
    LEFT JOIN 
        payments P FORCE INDEX (ix_userid) ON P.UserId = U.Id
    WHERE 
        U.StatusId = 1 
    GROUP BY
        U.Id
--------------

+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
| Id    | Name | CreditAmount | DebitAmount |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
|     1 | NULL |     47824.73 |    49580.71 |
|     2 | NULL |     46426.02 |    52019.69 |
...
| 19999 | NULL |     50041.10 |    47696.88 |
| 20000 | NULL |     51923.69 |    50349.38 |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+
18057 rows in set (0.75 sec)

Bye
```

Comment: I'll check this for a moment. Thanks again! +1

Comment: Sorry for the late udpate, I was working on different issues. I was able to test this, but still got the same results. Looking for the `my.cnf` file to check settings for optimization. This helped me a lot, I'll accept this after some more testings. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry Ross, can't accept your answer, but I did voted it up because it helped me a lot. We can't change any `properties`/`variables` on the `my.cnf` file, our server wouldn't allow that. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: I don't understand. Your question was "optimize my query", and my answer did just that. If the answer doesn't work on your system , I suggest trying it on another system (perhaps even sqlfiddle.com), as the system you are testing on appears to have performance issues unrelated to the query you are trying to optimize. And the answer you *did* accept, doesn't answer the question. <sigh>

Comment: Got your point Ross, I've tested your answer in our local servers, even on our production servers [which didn't work because of performance issues], but we're limited to modification of server settings. I've accepted the answer because I was thinking of other ways of improving the query, not just the query itself, but also the design.