# How do you add to a MySQL value to create a voting system?

Tags: php

I'm currently trying create a voting system allowing users to add votes to specific videos. I can retrieve the current vote number from the database table, but I don't know how to add one to this total and then reinsert this value into the database when a button is clicked. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Something like `UPDATE votes_table SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE video_id = ?` ?

Answer (score 8):

It's much better to keep a history of all votes, then work out the totals using `count(*)` and `group by`.

```
select answer, count(*) from vote group by answer;
```

This will avoid race conditions if two people try to vote at the same time, and you can add columns in your vote table for the users user id, session ID, ip address etc. which you can use to look for suspicious voting patterns later.

Comment: + one for the smart technique.

Comment: Yes, it definitely is!

Comment: however how would you manage a system with vote downs ? i dream of a wiki about practical database modeling with these kind of techniques.

Comment: @mpm There are a couple of ways to handle vote downs. You could add a score field with value either 1 or -1 for each fow, and use `sum(score)` instead of `count(*)`, or you could have a separate down vote table.

Answer (score 2):

Use a mysql query similar to this:

```
UPDATE table SET voteCount = voteCount+1 WHERE video = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate table of counts of votes and user votes.

You can try adding votes in own table in database for example:

```
INSERT INTO votes_tables (id, user_id, video_id, vote_up, vote_down, date) VALUES (NULL, '5', '10', '1', '', NOW());
```

In another table where you have lists of video store only value of video votes (increments, decrements statuses):

Upvote:

```
UPDATE votes_table SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE video_id = ?
```

Downvote:

```
UPDATE votes_table SET votes = votes - 1 WHERE video_id = ?
```

This method you can separate who and when is voted + votes of statistics. This method avoid is using `GROUP_BY` and can speed-up to returning result of data.

Using COUNT(*) or SUM() can occured speed down:

A row where is count(*) should be INDEX for speed improvements, so a index of data in table was increase due to performance speed up. Debate of perfomance: [Is it possible to speed up a sum() in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178441/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-sum-in-mysql)