# Laravel Optimise sum query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I would like to get sum go deposit, withdraw and net count. Currently, I have ~10,335,633 rows data(~1.8GB), it takes more than 7 seconds to calculate the sum. How should I improve my query to make it faster?

Query:

```
$depositQuery = Deposit::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->approved();
$withdrawQuery = Withdraw::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->approved();

if ($request->has('user_id')) {
    $depositQuery = $depositQuery->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
    $withdrawQuery = $withdrawQuery->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
}

$deposits = $depositQuery->sum('amount');
$withdraws = ($withdrawQuery->sum('amount')) * -1;
$net = $deposits + $withdraws;
```

Result:

```
Deposit     Withdraw     Net Amount
20,946.00   15,066.00    5,880.00
```

Comment: First: Index the `created_at` column.

Comment: Archiving less used/low value data, say unapproved transactions. Or else if it is a very common task to calculate the deposit and withdrawals, move the aggregates in a column of their own and update them with every approved transactions.

Comment: Archiving less used/low value data, say unapproved transactions. Or else if it is a very common task to calculate the deposit and withdrawals, move the aggregates in a column of their own and update them with every approved transactions.

Comment: Can you check your user_id, and created_at is indexed or not also please add you scopeApproved function so i can debug more

Comment: what does the `->approved()` function do?

Comment: Already index created_at and user_id, before index, it took longer than 7second.

Comment: @MrChrissss approved() basically is get approved transactions.

Comment: @CheamHuoySan yea but in that function do use something like '->get()'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, laravel eloquent doesn't have anything to do with the optimization of the `sum()`, it simply translates your code into SQL query. And getting into your question

> Remeber: You can't optimize the sum function itself *(unless you are some real jedi)

You have 1M records in your database, and MySQL sum will have to go through all the records to calculate the sum. and in that case, 7 seconds is okay I think. According to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2178441/2693543), `sum()` on a 7M record table took about 22 seconds. So depending on your schema, machine etc... velocity may vary a bit here and there.

**So how can you go ahead with improving the response time?**

Somehow you will have to reduce the number of records before giving it to `sum()` to process.

one way I suppose you can do is, you can calculate sums of 10k record batches/chunks and store it in a separate table, with appropriate date and time range. The broad term for this is **archiving**. Then when you have to calculate a sum for a given range of date, use the previous complete sum from the new table and use it. You could set up a chron job to update this table one's in a day or something to make sure the data is proper always.

Another way is to [partition MySQL tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html). Which also seems to be a promising way. Which is also kind of archiving. but I am not very experienced with it to make any comments on it. Google should help you with this.

The indexing on the columns like `created_at` and the column you use for approved scope should improve the response time, but not much as if you were leveraging the archiving technique.

Also, I have **MySQLmysql query cache** on an answer from the same link I specified above, [more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html). Which you can try employing. But as of mysql 8 it has been deprecated and moreover, it won't work as expected if you have multiple instances running and if you have partitioned tables.