# Optimize SUM() AND GROUP BY MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization

I have a table with 161886415 rows. When i run:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

It takes 0.0083 seconds.

But when i try to run:

```
SELECT A, SUM(B) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY A
```

It takes an infinite time

I already have an `A` and `B` index, `AB` and `BA` composite index

A is `date` and B is an `int`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison is misleading.  When you have a query like this:

```
select a.*
from table;
```

You are seeing the first rows returned, not all of them.  MySQL can start to return rows as quickly as it reads them.  By contrast, the aggregation query needs to read the entire table before returning a single row.

You might find that the aggregation query is faster if you have an index on `(A, B)`.  But you seem to already have this index.

Pretty much your best option is to filter down to a subset of the dates.

Comment: I cant filter a subset of the dates. I need the SUM from all.

Comment: @shadow . . . Unfortunately, you are probably stuck with bad `group by` performance then.

Answer (score 0):

First select is quite easy to process. Database engine can use table scan over heap stored data which is used when you try to retrieve bigger percentage of data stored in table.

You should look at your query plan which aggregate operator is being used. Also, you can edit your original post.

Index could be helpful. MariaDB offers column store for example. Depends on query and your speed expectations.

Similar issue dealing with SUM() performance [Is it possible to speed up a sum() in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178441/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-sum-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Your first query returned all 181 million rows in 8.3 milliseconds.  I think not.

The second query, as you will see from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` efficiently uses `INDEX(A, B)`.  Still it needs to read all 181 'rows' in that index, so it takes a long time.

Often in Data Warehouse applications, it is beneficial to build and maintain "Summary Tables" to speed things up -- significantly.  You might have a daily subtotal of `SUM(B)` for each `A`, then sum up the subtotals when you need it.

If you want to discuss thing further, provide more specifics on the table and the query.