# How can I increase performance while using SUM() with group by on large dataset

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I am using MySQL database with a table containing approx 1,2 M rows. I have indexes on ID as primary key and on position (this is parameter that is used for groupping). Despite that when I want to execute my query:

```
SELECT SUM(balance), position from table group by position.
```

it takes around 30 sec to get result. Due to buisness needs it may happen pretty often that user will have to summarize all or almost all rows.

Table structure is following:

```
ID. PK 
balance Float
account VARCHAR(10)
position VARCHAR(5).
```

I was trying to rebuild indexes but nothing has really changed. I was also trying to build some subqueries but again failed to achive any improvements.

Is there any chance to speed up this query?

Comment: Look at the execution plan and add indexes to speed up the slow operations https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/getting-an-execution-plan

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178441/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-sum-in-mysql

Comment: Are you aware that an index can cover more than one column? Index `(position, balance)` in a single index and it will greatly outperform two indexes on one column each.

Comment: If you already know that large aggregations are required frequently, cache the results. During data ingestion add the individual rows, but also add their data to a summary table (then query the summary table at report time). Or, more generically, build a data cube during data ingestion. https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/star-schema-olap-cube/

Comment: @MatBailie Adding complex index improved execution time to 1.7 sec (previously 34). Should have tried this earlier. THANKS!

Comment: Aside - `float` is never appropriate to use for monetary values unless you require to only represent your data approximately.

Comment: How often is "pretty often"? Reading 1.2M rows or index entries every time should be done sparely, even it it takes 2s to compute.

Comment: *Due to buisness needs it may happen pretty often* Does the user executes the shown query exactly? Without WHERE? If so then you may use pre-calculation into separate table which is performed in the trigger.

Comment: More on [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: This is what Indexed or Materialized Views are for, but MySQL does not support them.